# Make TextView click to next page

Tags: java, android, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

I want to be able to click on a TextView which will then direct me to a new page that will display a multi-level expandable list.

I have the expandable list created, and have made a new MainActivity.java file for it as it extends something different to the homepage

My manifest looks like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:label="Home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- name defines the class that handles setting up the Activity
         label will be the title for the activity
         theme defines the theme to use -->
    <activity android:name=".NLevelList"
        android:label="Advanced Search"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

I know I need to use an onClick Listener and have an onClick method in the MainActivity but I've been at it all morning and I don't understand how to do it, could someone please show me what to do

Comment: where is your MainActivity coe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire an intent from your listener to start the new activity.

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NLevelList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the available documentation and training

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#RespondToButton